# Make plain text to HTML but only links?

Tags: php, html, html-entities

The scenario is:

1. A user puts a lot content in a textarea that is saved to database.
2. The saved content are "ensure plain text" by using `htmlentities()`.

And when output to a webpage it shows like this (and the link is shown as plain text as well)

```
Hello there, how are you today. 
This text is saved and I want to show links, 
but the links are displayed like this: <a href="text">text</a>.

(because the html surrounding the link are &lt; and &gt;)
```

I've made it like this (plain text only) because I don't want users to mess up the the content with HTML tags etc.

Is it possible to replace `&gt;` and `&lt;` into < and > **but only when there is a link**? I'm not sure how to achieve this.

**UPDATE:**
A thought might be using a custom tag like `[mylink]actual link[/mylink]`. It would be OK as well. This might be a better solution? What are your thoughts?

Comment: so a plain text link would look like this: "&gt;<a href="#">link</a>&lt;"?

Comment: No &lt;a href="#"&gt;link&lt;/a&gt;

Comment: Are you using PHP?

Comment: Looks like `htmlentities` is somehow used twice. When storing text into the database, don't use `htmlentities`, but just escape the text for database special chars. Use `htmlentities` only when printing the text to a HTML page.

Comment: Yes sorry using PHP, I will add that tag

Comment: If I store the actual content that users put in there a lot of "crap" would be stored in the database (if user misuses the system). For me that seems unnessecary.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld I don't know what you are using this for, but you should note that this **does not protect you from XSS attacks**. You need more validation than just only allowing link tags if you want to prevent XSS.

Comment: If you do this thing a lot I suggest you look into using TinyMCE (maybe with the BBCode plugin).

Comment: @Chris - of course, this is just a part of a larger system :-)

Comment: @apokryfos - I don't see TinyMCE as a good option in my specific case, but thansk for the tip!

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld Good to hear. Best of luck with your project.

Comment: @Chris - thank you! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `htmlentities` use [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php):

> strip_tags — Strip HTML and PHP tags from a string

There is an option that allows to ignore certain tags. In your example:

```
$text="This <b>is</b> a <a href='#'>test</a>";
echo strip_tags($text,'<a>');
```

That will remove every HTML tag but the anchors.

Comment: Thank you! This what was I looking for!